# Query string syntax error in vb6 & SQL

Tags: sql, string, vb6

I can't figure out which part of this code is written incorrectly.

In my query string, i'm trying to collect a range of records between the values of sFrom and sTo. Basically, I want to make it so that out of all the control numbers that I collect from my database, the only ones that get displayed will be whatever the user inputs for the starting range (sFrom) and the ending range (sTo).

```
sQuery = "SELECT " & sFields & " FROM " & sTable &
         " Where store_id Like 'XXX'" & sFilter &
         " Where control_no > sFrom and < sTo " &
           order by " & sOrderBy
```

Comment: When you have a issue like this, just write `Debug.print sQuery`, then copy that copy into SQL Server (Other RDBMSs are available) and execute the query - that should tell you where the (first) issue is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to debug this is to see what the resultant SQL statement is and work from there.

Yours currently evaluates to something like

```
SELECT field, field2 FROM table Where store_id Like 'XXX'FilterString Where control_no > sFrom and < sTo order by field1
```

1. You can't have multiple WHERE clauses.
2. I expect your `sFilter` inclusion is very wrong, but it depends in what the exact value is.
3. `sFrom` and `sTo` are included as literals, not evaluated (See [tcarvin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10590838/588306))
4. Each part of the `WHERE` clause needs to be full and complete. You can't omit the field to check (See [Darrel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10590439/588306))

Answer (score 2):

This:

`" Where control_no > sFrom and < sTo "`

should probably be this:

`" Where control_no >= " & sFrom & " and control_no <= " & sTo`

(Assuming of course that sFrom and sTo are string variables populated with the numeric input from the user)

Comment: Hmm, also missing your line continuation characters and the `order by " & sOrderBy ` should be `"order by " & sOrderBy`

Answer (score 1):

You can't drop the control_no before the <

```
sQuery = "SELECT " & sFields & " FROM " & sTable & " Where store_id Like 'XXX'" & sFilter & " Where control_no > sFrom and control_no < sTo " & order by " & sOrderBy
```

Answer (score 1):

1. In `Like 'XXX'" & sFilter`, you have no space between `X`' and the next string.
2. You have no line continuation characters at all.
3. You have TWO Where clauses.
4. `sFrom` and `sTo` are literal strings. You probably meant to use them as variables.
5. You have no comparison between `control_no` and `sTo`.
6. You have no statement between `sFilter` and the surrounding SQL.
7. You have no double quotes before `order by`.
8. Just as a style choice, you are not consistent in your SQL keyword capitalisation.

Now, put it all together:

```
sQuery = "SELECT " & sFields & " FROM " & sTable & _
         " WHERE store_id LIKE 'XXX'" & _
         " AND " & sFilter & _
         " AND control_no > " & sFrom & _
         " AND control_no < " & sTo & _
         " ORDER BY " & sOrderBy
```